# Heroku won't reset my database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, heroku

I have been trying to run **$ heroku pg:reset**  from the command line but I believe I'm not putting in the database correctly. I've tried a number of variations.

I ran **$ heroku config | grep POSTGRESQL** to get the database name which prints as

```
HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_PINK_URL: postgres://naknaswvxfvuup:QK2dHYNMZ_va10lDgMDo4S0BIM@ec2-23-21-161-255.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/db7eute4gu4mcb
```

I've tried running everything from

**#1**

```
$ heroku pg:reset HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_PINK_URL: postgres://naknaswvxfvuup:QK2dHYNMZ_va10lDgMDo4S0BIM@ec2-23-21-161-255.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/db7eute4gu4mcb
```

**#2**

```
$ heroku pg reset postgres://naknaswvxfvuup:QK2dHYNMZ_va10lDgMDo4S0BIM@ec2-23-21-161-255.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/db7eute4gu4mcb
```

**#3**

```
$ heroku pg:reset db7eute4gu4mcb
```

and other variations. Please let me know how to correctly note this as I keep getting either an error or this text from the commmand line " `!    Unknown database: db7eute4gu4mcb. Valid options are: DATABASE_URL, HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_PINK_URL"`

I'm currently at 10.4 on the Ruby on Rails tutorial. Thanks!

Answer (score 18):

You should specify a DATABASE when run `heroku pg:reset`. This is the syntax:

```
heroku pg:reset <DATABASE>
```

To know the value of , you can run:

```
heroku pg:info
```

It will return DATABASE_URL, something like: **HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_GRAY_URL**
Then you can reset your database:

```
heroku pg:reset HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_GRAY_URL
```

In your case, to reset database run:

```
heroku pg:reset HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_PINK_URL
```

Comment: Finally! someone has provided the correct answer! thanks again Kien

Comment: Thank you! Didn't realize you literally had to put in `HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_PINK_URL`. thought that had a value

Comment: I tried this, using my correct db url and I now get the following in my heroku logs because something broke: http://pastebin.com/Ce5RunSq What should I do in this case? Thanks.

Comment: @m_antis you should run 'heroku run rake db:migrate' to recreate database

Answer (score 2):

this is how it worked for me 
(replace app-staging with your app's name, do not replace DATABASE_URL, this is how heroku now finds the app's db)

```
heroku pg:reset DATABASE_URL --confirm app-staging
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have your authentication information exported to the shell environment, you should be fine with just passing the name of the database. For example:

```
PGPASSWORD='foobarbaz'
export PGPASSWORD
heroku pg:reset pink
```

There are certainly other ways to use the reset command, but IMHO this is the easiest.